# ASP.NET Core Windows Authentication pass through from UI website to API

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication

IIS on Windows Server 2012 setup with 2 projects:

- example.com: `ASP.NET Core MVC` project with `VueJS` as javascript framework.
- api.example.com: `ASP.NET Core Web API` project whichs feeds the UI project.

The `example.com` is setup using Windows Authentication, the `api.example.com` is setup with both Anonymous and Windows Authentication.

Both projects have a seperated `Application Pool`.

Everything is working fine except when I go to the `example.com` website, I get a prompt to input my AD credentials for `example.com`, after that I get another one for `api.example.com`.

So the user needs to enter his credentials twice. Is there a way to reduce this to one and send the credentials to both websites?

I am using Google Chrome as browser to use the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok reduced the login to zero. Disabled the Windows authentication on the `example.com` because all authentication is done on the API project so no need to apply it here. Then added the `api.example.com` under `Internet Explorer > Settings > Security > Intranet sites` and kow the client can work directly without applying credentials when working inside the domain.